# Delete multiple documents based on group by and sort operation

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new here with MongoDB I need your help. I want to delete multiple documents from a collection based on certain condition i.e. grouping based on empID and deleting the records except latest record for that empID.

Suppose my dataset looks like:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    employeeId: "50052196",
    name: "abc",
    lastUpdatedOn: ISODate("2022-01-10T10:25:38.859+00:00")
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    employeeId: "50052197",
    name: "xyz",
    lastUpdatedOn: ISODate("2022-01-17T10:25:38.859+00:00")
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    employeeId: "50052198",
    name: "pqr",
    lastUpdatedOn: ISODate("2022-01-17T10:25:38.859+00:00")
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    employeeId: "50052196",
    name: "abc",
    lastUpdatedOn: ISODate("2022-01-12T11:30:58.435+00:00")
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    employeeId: "50052196",
    name: "abc",
    lastUpdatedOn: ISODate("2022-01-15T15:45:00.159+00:00")
  }
]
```

In above dataset, `employeeID : 50052196` is duplicate document which got inserted periodically along with field `lastUpdatedOn`. As `lastUpdatedOn` is nothing but record/document creation date.

Now, I want to keep the document having latest lastUpdatedOn value i.e. `lastUpdatedOn:2022-01-15T15:45:00.159+00:00` for `employeeID : 50052196`.

I have gone through MongoDB documentation and I found that we are not able to write delete query along with group by and sort operation Or if we choose Aggregate Pipeline then we are not able to delete documents inside aggregate.
I was checking the option of `Bulk.find.remove()`, but again I'm not able to figure out how to group the employeeId.

Another approach I had in mind, based on some condition, I will add one field i.e. `isActive: true`. And using normal `deleteMany()` operation I can delete `isActive: false` documents. But as per policy I can not modify the documents.
The insertion operation in the collection is handled by third party-application, which we can not modify.

As the documents are larger in numbers, and I wanted to write a code which will be less time and resource consuming at the same time it should be adhering to best practices. Help is much appreciated. Can anyone please suggest me good option to tackle out this situation. Help is much appreciated.

NOTE: Same type of deletion code I have to write for multiple MongoDB collections. It is kind of clean-up script that I'm thinking of to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever pipeline you want and add an [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage at the end, this will overwrite the chosen collection.

for example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      lastUpdatedOn: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$employeeId",
      root: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$root"
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "collection"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tFYQUXHiXde)

A more controlled way in code, iterate user by user:

```
const userIds = await db.collection.distinct('employeeId');
for (let i = 0; i < userIds.length; i++) {
    const userId = userIds[i];
    const employeeRecords = await db.collection.find({ 'employeeId': userId }).sort({ lastUpdatedOn: -1 }).toArray();
    employeeRecords.pop();
    await db.collection.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: employeeRecords.map(v => v._id) } });
}
```

(this should run in parallel. It's written in a for loop for clarity)

Comment: thanks for quick reply. What I understood from answer is that, the final result of group by we are overwriting to original collection. Is it right or wrong?
If we are overwriting to original collection and the result after group-by is having large number of documents, how the performance looks like?

Comment: Performance is obviously quite bad due to the fact you're grouping the entire collection in memory, I would also not recommend doing something like this in production. however this is the only way to do this in a single db call. any other solution will require multiple calls.

Comment: Understood. Can you please help me with some code, how it should look like in case of multiple calls? So that will show some prototype to the team to discuss upon further.

Comment: I added some puesdo code for how i'd do it with multiple calls ( basically iterating each user at a time ). much easier to manage resources, limit concurrency. you can even do it in increments, like 200 user batch at a time.

Comment: Much Thanks @tom-slabbaert. Can you just help with me how we can implement this 'await' using python or native mongodb code. I have not found anything similar to await in mongodb.

Comment: i python you don't need await at all as `pymongo` does it OOB, it's just `nodejs` way to resolve a promise.